# Awk-Command Line to Script Arguments as Variable to Search For Specific Field

Tags: linux, variables, awk

So I'm trying to write a script that will take an argument from the command line and use said variable as the field parameter to print. The script must use any number or NF.

So,

```
echo a b c | ./awkprint.sh 1
```

would print the first field (a)

and,

```
echo a b c | ./awkprint.sh NF
```

would print the last field (c).

Here's what I have for the line in the script

```
awk -v awkvar=$1 '{print $awkvar}'
```

It works perfectly for any number that I use on the command line...however as soon as I use NF it seems to treat it as $0 and print all fields so I get:

```
echo a b c | ./awkprint.sh NF

a b c
```

instead of,

```
echo a b c | ./awkprint.sh NF

c
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so because the string `"NF"` is converted into `0`.

`awk` conversion process states that any string that can't be converted into a valid number is evaluates to `0`, thus, giving you `print $0`.

From `man awk`:

> Variable Typing And Conversion
>
> ```
>   Variables and fields may be (floating  point)  numbers,  or
>    strings,  or  both.   How the value of a variable is inter‐
>    preted depends upon its context.   If  used  in  a  numeric
>    expression,  it  will  be treated as a number; if used as a
>    string it will be treated as a string.
>    ...
>    When a string must be converted to a number, the conversion
>    is  accomplished using strtod(3).
> ```

And from `man strtod`:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>   These functions return the converted value, if any.
>
>   ...
>   If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the
>   value of nptr is stored in the location referenced by
>   endptr.
> ```

To do what you want, you may write -- as pointed by @Ed Morton:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v awkvar=$1 '{print (awkvar == "NF" ? $NF : $awkvar)}'
```

Notice, though, that `$0` will be printed both when `awkvar` is not a convertable-to-integer string and when it is `"NF"`.

A more appropriate check would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v awkvar=$1 '{
    if (awkvar == "NF") { print; }
    else if (int(awkvar) != 0) { print $awkvar; }
    else { print "Error: invalid field specifier;" }
}'
```

You may also check if `int(awkvar) <= NF` -- to avoid printing `""`.

Comment: `awk -v awkvar=$1 '{print (awkvar=="NF"?$NF:$awkvar)}'`

Comment: @EdMorton This is just a common compression of an `if`, does not answer the reason why `NF` was not working.

Comment: That's correct and that's why I deleted my posting of it as an answer so that your answer would get the acceptance vote instead of mine since you put the effort into explaining it but your code has some issues so the OP may have chose mine as the right answer when your answer IMHO would be more appropriate for him/her to accept.